Elastic Search Sorting behavior
I have a table in database with a single column and values this way -
T-RT-001
T-RT-002
T-RT-003
TESTDOC-000001-B
TESTDOC-000001-C
TESTDOC-000001-D

when i run the below SQL with order by i get the results this way -
TESTDOC-000001-B
TESTDOC-000001-C
TESTDOC-000001-D
T-RT-001
T-RT-002
T-RT-003

i now created an index that uses analyzer with lowercase filter
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "CustomTokenizer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "type": "custom"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "CustomTokenizer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

i then indexed few docs with the same names as above.
i now ran this query -
GET default_index001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "Match_all": {
    }
  }, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "Name.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 100
}

it returns the results in this order -
T-RT-001
T-RT-002
T-RT-003
TESTDOC-000001-B
TESTDOC-000001-C
TESTDOC-000001-D

why is there a difference in the output? what sorting does database apply and elastic applies?
Elastic version 8.1.13
SQL Server 2019 with Latin1_General_CI_AS as collation setting

Elasticsearch doesn't have a very strong collation support, but you can get results similar to Latin1_General_CI_AS bu using ICU collator:
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "val": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "sort": {  
            "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
            "index": false,
            "alternate": "shifted",
            "strength": "secondary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"val": "T-RT-001"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"val": "T-RT-002"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"val": "T-RT-003"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"val": "testdoc-000001-B"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"val": "TESTDOC-000001-C"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"val": "testdoc-000001-D"}
{"index":{"_id":7}}

POST test/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "val.sort": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

